# How to implement `tail` command using CL?

Tags: common-lisp

"with-open-file" will read from the beginning of a file. If the file is VERY big how to read the last 20 lines efficiently ?

Sincerely!

Comment: see http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_file_p.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This opens a file, reads the final byte, and closes the file.

```
(defun read-final-byte (filename)
  (with-open-file (s filename
                     :direction :input
                     :if-does-not-exist :error)
    (let ((len (file-length s)))
      (file-position s (1- len))  ; 0-based position.
      (read-char s nil))))        ; don't error if reading the end of the file.
```

If you want to specifically read the last `n` lines, you will have to read back an indeterminate number of bytes until you get `n+1` newlines. In order to do this, you will either have to do block reads backwards (faster but will wind up in reading unneeded bytes), or byte-reads (slower but allows precision and a slightly more obvious algorithm).

I suspect `tail` has a reasonable algorithm applied for this, so it would likely be worth reading `tail`'s [source](https://github.com/gvvaughan/GNU-coreutils/blob/master/src/tail.c) for a guideline.